# Maxima plots auto save

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

I am using Maxima and I have a lot of resulting plots that I want to save on drive for other uses (making GIF...etc)

This is what I am looking at:
[image]
[image]

Is there any code that can autosave the plots instead of having to save it manually one by one?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one approach is to specify a file name in the arguments of `plot2d`. Then the plot is output directly to the file and it doesn't show up in the GUI. E.g.,

```
plot2d (sin(x), [x, 0, 10], [png_file, "mysinplot.png"]);
```

`plot2d` recognizes `png_file`, `pdf_file`, `ps_file` and `svg_file`. In each case, `? png_file`, etc, will show some info about that.

Note that there isn't any file output flag for GIF output. The closest thing is PNG which is similar to GIF.

I think `draw` also recognizes different file formats but I don't know about that without searching the documentation.

If you are generating a lot of plots, it might be convenient to automatically generate file names via `sconcat`, e.g. `sconcat("myplot", i, ".png")` produces `"myplot10.png"` when `i` is equal to 10.

Comment: Thank you for your answering, I know this way but its for example for an equation with one or two variables but in my case there are a lot of (for and if) loops thats related to each other so my question is if there's any way to save the output plot directly to a directory folder location? 

Sincerely

Comment: `plot2d` writes files into the folder named by `maxima_tempdir`. So you can set `maxima_tempdir` to some suitable folder name and outputs from `png_file`, etc., will go there. If you are working on MS Windows, I don't know whether you need to write "/" in the folder name, or "\". Try it both ways and see what works. If you try "/", probably you have to write "\\" in order to get a single "\" in the folder name.

Comment: I think its "/" for example what I made is 
maxima_tempdir: "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/Animation"; but its not useful until now, what I get as a result is one pdf file that is not opening and one or two plots out of several that shown for a moment and disappeared finally!